# How to adapt a set iterator to behave like a map iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, encapsulation

I have a class `Foo` that contains a `map` and provides `begin()` and `end()` functions to iterate over it:

```
class Foo {
  typedef std::map<int, double> Container;
  typedef Container::const_iterator const_iterator;
  Container c_;
 public:
  const_iterator begin() const { return c_.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return c_.end(); }
  void insert(int i, double d) { c_[i] = d; }
  // ...

};
```

Now I would like to change it internally from `std::map<int, double>` to just a `std::set<int>`, but I don't want to break any client code.

So the `double d` in the `insert` function would now just be ignored. And the following code should still be valid, where `it->second` will now just always be `0.0`:

```
Foo foo;
for(Foo::const_iterator it = foo.begin(); it != foo.end(); ++it) {
  std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

How can I make these changes in the `Foo` class?

In other words, how can I provide a `Foo::const_iterator` that adapts the new internal `std::set<int>::const_iterator` to behave like the old `std::map<int,double>::const_iterator`?

**UPDATE:** The reason I want to get rid of the `map` is memory efficiency. I have millions of `Foo` instances and cannot afford to store the `double` values in them.

Comment: To be honest, that sounds like a really bad idea. Keeping the contract compatible when the semantics have completely changed isn’t meaningful.

Comment: @KonradRudolph C++ has been doing that since day one.

Comment: @wilhelm: That’s true. But not a reason to do the same.

Comment: @Konrad true. I was kidding: in C++ it was part of the (now questionable?) design. Here it's an apparent consequence, something we might be able to avoid. Backward-compatibility is a pita, something to do only when you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 2):

Would using

```
std::set<std::pair<int, double> >
```

not be sufficient for this comparability?

Failing that you can always write your own iterator which wraps the std::list iterator and provides `first` and `second` members. Basically your operator++ would call operator++ on the real iterator etc. and the de-referencing operator could return either a temporary std::pair (by value) or a reference to a std::pair that lives within the iterator itself (if your legacy code can deal with that).

**Update, slightly contrived example, might work depending on your scenario:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Foo {
  typedef std::set<int> Container;
  typedef Container::const_iterator legacy_iterator;
  Container c_;

  // legacy iterator doesn't have a virtual destructor (probably?), shouldn't
  // be a problem for sane usage though
  class compat_iterator : public legacy_iterator {
  public:
     compat_iterator(const legacy_iterator& it) : legacy_iterator(it) {
     }

     const std::pair<int,double> *operator->() const {
        static std::pair<int,double> value;
        value = std::make_pair(**this, 0.0);
        // Not meeting the usual semantics!
        return &value;
     }
  };
 public:
  typedef compat_iterator const_iterator;

  const_iterator begin() const { return c_.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return c_.end(); }

};



int main() {

  Foo foo;
  for(Foo::const_iterator it = foo.begin(); it != foo.end(); ++it) {
     std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: No, I should have said this: The reason I need a `set` now is I want to save memory. I have millions of `Foo` instances and cannot afford to store the double anymore.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add an example of something that implements compatibility with only minimal extra overheads. Of course taking the address of either of the members of the pair would be a bad idea now, but if the legacy code doesn't rely on it then it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>

struct Funky
{
    int first;
    static const double second;

    Funky(int i)
    :   first(i)
    {}
};

const double Funky::second = 0.0;

bool operator<(const Funky& lhs, const Funky& rhs)
{
    return lhs.first < rhs.first;
}

class Foo
{
private:
    //std::map<int,double> m_data;
    std::set<Funky> m_data;
public:
    //typedef std::map<int,double>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef std::set<Funky>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return m_data.begin();
    }

    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return m_data.end();
    }

    void insert(int i, double d)
    {
        //m_data.insert(std::make_pair(i, d));
        m_data.insert(i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.insert(23, 9.0);
    for(Foo::const_iterator it=foo.begin(), iend=foo.end(); it!=iend; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing I should point out is that anything that tries to change `it->second` will now fail -- so you might want to get rid of the const. Alternatively, you might want people to know what's going on...

Comment: (I do think the whole idea of doing this sort of thing is rather ill-advised, for the record...)

Comment: I do not think that redefinition of `operator<` is necessary, default should be sufficient.

Comment: AFAICS it's completely necessary (and g++ agrees) -- why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Comeau also agrees, incidentally.

Comment: @sgolodetz I really don't know why I made that comment, sorry. I dreamed of a default `operator<` that calls `operator<` on all fields of an object (similar to the default implementations of `equals` in `Java`).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the lines of

```
operator int()(const std::pair<int, double>& p) const {
    return p.first;
}
```

maybe within some wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can define a `fake_pair` class that implements `first` and `second` and put a `set<fake_pair>` inside `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not completely.  The problem is you are changing your interface, which will always break your clients.  I would recommend you create two new functions of newBegin and newEnd (or similar) which has your new behaviour.  Your old interface you keep this the same but mark it as depreciated.  The implementation of this old interface can use one of the work around described by the others.